# Slide transition between html files using JQuery and AJAX to navigate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to implement the slide transition effect between many separate html files in my website.  I've been searching for hours but I can't find an example for what I'm trying to do without having redesign the website.  I'm using JQuery and AJAX to validate the selections on the pages and then move to the selected ones after some server side validation.  Is this possible with my current design? Thanks

```
//JavaScript function
function getValue(aval) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Services.aspx/getSelection',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{"aSelection":"' + aval + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.d);
            if (data.d == 1) {
                window.location.href = "InsuredReason.html";
            }
            if (data.d == 2) {
                window.location.href = "AgentInfo.html";
            }
            if (data.d == 3) {
                window.location.href = "ContratistaInfo.html";
            }
            if (data.d == 4) {
                window.location.href = "VisitorInfo.html";
            }
        },
        error: function (er) {
            //alert(er.d);
        }
    });

  }

<!--HTML-->
    <nav id="razonAseg">
        <br>
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Asegurado" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Asegurado" border="0" onclick="getValue('1')"/>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Agente" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Agente" border="0" onclick="getValue('2')"/>
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Contratista" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Contratista" border="0" onclick="getValue('3')"/>
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Visitante" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Visitante" border="0" onclick="getValue('4')"/>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You cannot use `window.location.href` as you lose control of the page at that point. Instead you need to get your server to respond with the appropriate pages (HTML) and slide that content into view. We have spent that last 2 years perfecting this type of transitioning, on top of a standard MVC.net website, and it is quite a complex problem to solve "properly".

Comment: Q: What is your server-side technology? Might be able to provide simple example if you use a tech familiar to me :)

Comment: Thanks TrueBlueAussie:  I'm using VS 2013 ASPX System.Web.Services.WebMethods() and I'm coding in VB to handle some server side validations and continue navigating. `    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function continueNav() As String

        Dim result As String = "false"

        If HttpContext.Current.Session("option1") = 1 Or HttpContext.Current.Session("option2") = 1 Or HttpContext.Current.Session("option3") = 1 Or HttpContext.Current.Session("option4") = 1 Then
            result = "true"
        End If

        Return result

    End Function`

Comment: That pattern is too easy to hack. Anyone could change the script, client-side, to bypass your validation and go to any page. Best hide all that server-side and return the resulting page's HTML rather than a number saying which page to load. e.g. use standard controller methods.

Comment: Forgive my last comment, I still don't know how to include the code in the comments.  I'll take your advice into consideration.  How about the slide transition effect? What do you recommend? I've seen many plugins out there and jQuery Mobile, but most of them require creating many div elements within the same page, and that is not my case.

Comment: You will need a few things. A parent div covering the area to be replaced (e.g. the whole page), and one div for each panel (i.e. 2). It is these divs that slide. The trick is to strip out the parts of the page you do not want from the HTML received. The transition is typically just animation of the left margin of the div from 0 to -width (panel going out) and from width to 0 (panel coming in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to redirect, better update some area of the page with content of html files.

HTML could be:

```
<nav id="razonAseg">
    <br>
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Asegurado" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Asegurado" border="0" onclick="getValue('1')"/>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Agente" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Agente" border="0" onclick="getValue('2')"/>
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Contratista" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Contratista" border="0" onclick="getValue('3')"/>
    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Visitante" width="315" height="628" class="smooth" id="Visitante" border="0" onclick="getValue('4')"/>
</nav>
<div id="content"></div>
```

And javascript would not redirect, but update the content:

```
function getValue(aval) {
    if (aval == 1) {
        filename = "InsuredReason.html";
    }
    if (aval == 2) {
        filename  = "AgentInfo.html";
    }
    if (aval == 3) {
        filename  = "ContratistaInfo.html";
    }
    if (aval == 4) {
        filename  = "VisitorInfo.html";
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Services.aspx/'+filename,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            $('#content').html(data);//where data is content of html file
        },
        error: function (er) {
            //alert(er.d);
        }
   });

}
```

Comment: Where are the requested transitions?

Comment: By using this technique, will I be able to then return the page from the server to then apply the slide effect that I'm looking for? Can you provide examples of how to code the effect or what plugin is easier to understand and use?

Comment: To create sliding you can use some jquery slider plugin, for example https://plugins.jquery.com/anythingslider/